# Unable to wire Spring-Integration with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-integration, spring-security-oauth2

I am a complete noob with Spring Integration Framework.

I am trying to consume a REST API that uses OAuth2.  I am using Spring Integration xml-based configuration.

**My issue is that cannot seem to get the Gateway and the Rest Template wired properly to send the body (multi-part) for the token request**

This is in my spring integration config file:

**spring-integration-context.xml**

```
<!-- Rest Template -->
<bean id="oAuth2RestTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientCredentialsResource"/>
</bean>

<!-- Used by Rest Template -->
<bean id= "clientCredentialsResource"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.client.ClientCredentialsResourceDetails">
    <property name="clientId" value="${oauth2.clientId}" />
    <property name="clientSecret" value="${oauth2.clientSecret}" />
    <property name="accessTokenUri" value="${oauth2.accessTokenUri}" />
</bean>

<!-- Channels for requesting token -->
<int:channel id="tokenRequestChannel"/>
<int:channel id="tokenResponseChannel"/>

<!-- Gateway for requesting token -->
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="authRequestGateway"
                           request-channel="tokenRequestChannel"
                           url="${oauth2.endPointUri}"
                           reply-timeout="30000"
                           http-method="GET"
                           rest-template="oAuth2RestTemplate"
                           reply-channel="tokenResponseChannel"
                           charset="UTF-8"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

To obtain the initial token, I know I need to POST my credentials in the header similar to this:

```
Method: POST
Authorization: Basic <base64-encoded clientId:clientSecret>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

And a adding multi-part (form) to the body

```
grant_type=client_credentials&scope=read
```

The API requires the string `grant_type=client_credentials&scope=read` to be in the request’s body (not the URL) as this is a `POST` (not a `GET`).

I have tried a few things (too many to remember/recount all) but **I am not sure where/how to put the payload into my request.**

I am missing something (obvious?) and I don't know what it is at this point.

This is what I get in the logs (request/response):

> 2016-11-10 16:46:22.429 DEBUG 6384 --- [ask-scheduler-3]
>   s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  :
>   sun.net.www.MessageHeader@2d1f9cc810 pairs: {POST
>   [redacted]/oauth/token HTTP/1.1: null}{Authorization: Basic
>   [redacted]}{Accept:
>   application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded}{Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded}{Cache-Control: no-cache}{Pragma:
>   no-cache}{User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_72}{Host:
>   [redacted]}{Connection: keep-alive}{Content-Length: 29}
>   2016-11-10 16:46:22.584 DEBUG 6384 --- [ask-scheduler-3]
>   s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  :
>   sun.net.www.MessageHeader@29200db310 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 **400 Bad
>   Request**}{Cache-Control: no-cache}{Pragma: no-cache}{Content-Type:
>   application/json; charset=utf-8}{Expires: -1}{Server:
>   [redacted]}{[redacted]}{[redacted]}{Date: Fri, 11 Nov 2016 00:46:48 GMT}{Content-Length: 46}
>   2016-11-10 16:46:22.586 ERROR 6384 --- [ask-scheduler-3]
>   o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   :
>   org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: **HTTP request
>   execution failed for URI
>   [redacted];
>   nested exception is error="access_denied", error_description="Access
>   token denied."**  at
>   org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:409)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
>     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) **Caused by:
>   error="access_denied", error_description="Access token denied."**     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:142)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.client.ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider.java:44)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:142)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.createRequest(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:105)  at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:615)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:595)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:516)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:382)
>     ... 30 more **Caused by: error="invalid_request",
>   error_description="OAuth Error", message="{ "error": "invalid_scope"
>   }"**  at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.deserialize(OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.java:120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.deserialize(OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.java:33)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2913)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:225)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:205)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport$AccessTokenErrorHandler.handleError(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:235)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:667)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:620)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:588)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:137)
>     ... 41 more

So, from what I can tell, I am getting an "Access Denied" message because I am unable to set the scope in the body of the request.

*Note1*

Also, I already looked at the code in the sample projects and did not see an answer to my issue.

*Note2*

I have verified (via POSTMAN) that the credentials, endpoints(URIs), scope, etc. are correct.

**UPDATE 1**

Based on comments from @Artem-Bilan, I changed the method to `POST` and added the code below to include the body in the request.

```
<!-- Add Payload -->
<int:inbound-channel-adapter id="oauth2ChannelAdapter" channel="tokenRequestChannel"
                             ref="grantAndScope" method="getGrantTypeAndScope">
    <!-- Triggering requests every 5 seconds -->
    <int:poller fixed-delay="5000" />
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<!-- Bean with Grant & Scope Payload -->
<bean id="grantAndScope" class="com.AuthTypeAndScopeInfo"/>
```

**AuthTypeAndScopeInfo.java**

```
public class AuthTypeAndScopeInfo {

    /* adds grant type and scope as body to message */
    public MultiValueMap<String, String> getGrantTypeAndScope() {
        // Create the request body as a MultiValueMap
        MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();

        body.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        body.add("scope", "read");

        return body;
    }
}
```

The results, however, are the same :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I ended up not using the `Oauth2RestTemplate`.

Instead, I used the code below.  The code basically starts by creating a `Map` payload (as suggested by Artem in his answer) and injects the headers for the first request.

Then it uses the response from the first request (which contains an access token) to inject the obtained token in the header of all subsequent requests.

There may be some room for optimization here but for now, this will suffice my needs.

**AuthTypeAndScopeInfo.java**

```
public class AuthTypeAndScopeInfo {

    /* adds grant type and scope as body to message */
    public MultiValueMap<String, String> getGrantTypeAndScope() {
        // Create the request body as a MultiValueMap
        MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();

        body.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        body.add("scope", "read");

        return body;
    }
}
```

**spring-integration-context.xml**

```
<!-- Add Payload -->
<int:inbound-channel-adapter id="oauth2ChannelAdapter" channel="preTokenRequestChannel"
                             ref="grantAndScope" method="getGrantTypeAndScope">
    <!-- Triggering requests every 5 seconds -->
    <int:poller fixed-delay="5000" />
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<!-- POJO with Grant & Scope Payload -->
<bean id="grantAndScope" class="com.AuthTypeAndScopeInfo"/>

<!-- Adding headers for Token Request -->
<int:header-enricher input-channel="preTokenRequestChannel" 
                     output-channel="tokenRequestChannel">
    <int:header name="Authorization" value="Basic <clientId:clientSecret>"/>
    <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
</int:header-enricher>

<!-- Channels for requesting token -->
<int:channel id="tokenRequestChannel"/>
<int:channel id="tokenResponseChannel"/>

<!-- Channels for Authenticated requests (with valid token) -->
<int:channel id="authenticatedRequestChannel"/>
<int:channel id="authenticatedResponseChannel"/>

<!-- Gateway for requesting token -->
<!-- REST request to authorization server for a token -->
<!-- replies time out after 30 seconds -->
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="tokenRequestGateway"
                           request-channel="tokenRequestChannel"
                           url="${security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri}"
                           reply-timeout="30000"
                           http-method="POST"
                           reply-channel="tokenResponseChannel"
                           charset="UTF-8"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<!-- Adding headers for Authenticated Request (contains newly obtained token) -->
<int:chain input-channel="tokenResponseChannel"
           output-channel="authenticatedRequestChannel">
    <int:header-enricher>
        <!-- Adds token_type and the actual (authenticated) 
             access_token to the header of the next request 
             (overwriting the Basic <...> previous entry) -->
        <int:header name="Authorization" overwrite="true"
                    expression="#jsonPath(payload,'$.token_type') + ' ' + #jsonPath(payload,'$.access_token')" />
    </int:header-enricher>
</int:chain>

<!-- REST request with pre-authorized token -->
<!-- replies time out after 30 seconds -->
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="authenticatedRequestGateway"
                           request-channel="authenticatedRequestChannel"
                           url="${security.oauth2.client.endPointUri}"
                           reply-timeout="30000"
                           http-method="GET"
                           reply-channel="authenticatedResponseChannel"
                           charset="UTF-8"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you have really to provide `POST` instead of your current `http-method="GET"` and send the message to that gateway with the `payload` as a `Map` of those required pairs.

Comment: Thanks for replying, if you look at the stacktrace, the first call is a `POST` request with the correct headers (i.e. `Content-Type`, `Authorization`) but, AFAICT it's coming from the `OAuth2RestTemplate` exchange - I could try again changing it to a `POST` - As a newbie, I am not sure I know how to "send the message to that gateway with the `payload` as a `Map`" - I can construct the `Map` no problem but how do I send the message as a `payload`?

Comment: I'll take a look into your stack trace, but meanwhile, please, let us know how do you interact with the `tokenRequestChannel` at all. That is exactly an input for that http gateway to send messages

Comment: Well, I don't know what that `POST` means in logs. I have never worked with OAuth, but I only see `http-method="GET"` in the config and that scares me. Plus I said you already that to have `grant_type=client_credentials&scope=read` in the body of the `POST` you have to build an appropriate `Map` as a `payload` before sending message to the request channel of that HTTP gateway.

Comment: Thanks! - away from office most of the day.  I'll try your suggestions and report back

Comment: So I added the `Map` as payload but the template still does not seem to recognize it.